# How to build a switch with Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a small circuit with a battery and a lamp. If I close the circuit the lamp will turn on, otherwise will turn off.

[image: Example]

I want to create a very small wireless switch. It will have only 2 signals to understand:

- Turn On (close the circuit)
- Turn Off (open the circuit)

The circuit will work with a 3V battery. And it need to be as small as possible. So, I think the Bluetooth will be the best. There are other good technology?

What I want is a start point. Where can I find a good book/tutorial to start this project? Or, if this is easy to say, how I build this switch?

Comment: I would like to do almost the same thing and I would like to know if you succeed it and how ? I have done a small circuit and I would like to do three things:
-Link to the right of the circuit OR
-Link to the left of the circuit OR
-Link to the ground So I need to build a bluetooth with a three way switch.

Comment: Hi @KevinBeauchamps, yes, I did it. This question was in the very fist phase of my project. And with the good answer from Gustavo Litovsky, a new world open for me. The answer is... ARDUINO. There are a lot of devices for arduino that use Bluetooh. One smaller that I found was here: https://tiny-circuits.com/ There are other models, but arduino is the answer. Search what you like more. Have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BLE there are two popular devices:

CC2540 from TI

nRF8001 from Nordic Semiconductor

Both use BLE. You can then connect a relay to them to enable a switch. They have development platforms you can buy rather inexpensively and use (look at the key fob).

Comment: Great, this is a start point. It look like a small computer and I can configure a lot of things..

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any experience with microcontrollers? To my knowledge (someone please correct me) BT modules have a serial data interface and require mode and configuration changes via said interface. You can't just hook up a couple of switches to it.

I'd suggest spending some time with a microcontroller devkit, one that has wireless options. You could do it over Wi-Fi with OpenPicus (sorry, no link, I'm on my phone). 
Google for wireless microcontroller development board and get familiar with it. That should get you started.